# IE11 Selenium WebDriverException: Failed to navigate. This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

My selenium tests are not running on IE11. I had done all the checks required (as in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration). I still bump into this error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to navigate to http://myapp. This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed

Answer (score 1):

Before you navigate, switch to the window

```
new_window = self.driver.window_handles[1]   
self.driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
```

Comment: Will try that. The same code other wise works on another IE11. This is a specific example where I'm trying to run selenium on a vm on Azure.